# Keras functional api input shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

My model definition is:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(28,28))
dense = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")
x = dense(inputs)
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(10)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="mnist_model")
```

And I will train the network with:

```
model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=10, epochs=30, verbose=2)
```

which `x_train`'s shape is (55000, 28, 28) and `y_train`'s shape is (55000,) and I get this error:

```
ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (10, 1)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (10, 28, 10))
```

Comment: you miss a Flatten layer in your network to pass from 3D to 2D

Comment: 55000 is the number of samples not data shape

Answer (score 1):

What @Marco Cerliani said means you should change your code to

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(28,28))
output = keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
output = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(output)
output = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(output)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(10)(output)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="mnist_model")
```

Please read the `tensorflow` [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials) and [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide) if you're a beginner . You will find the answer of your question if you read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) .